# Случайный выбор из двух фраз (слов)

Tags: c#, случайные-числа

Подскажите, имеется ли какой-нибудь простой метод выбора из двух фраз. Например, реализующий такое

```
Random r = new Random();
string stroka ="стакан";
switch(r.Next(2))
{
     case 0:
          stroka += " холодный";
          break;
     case 1:
          stroka += " теплый";
          break;
}
```

Этот код слишком грамоздкий, есть ли какое либо сокращение? Например:

*функция*(стакан {теплый|холодный});

Comment: всё, спасибо всем) из всего ниженаписанного сделал функцию:

        public string rand(string one, string two)
        {
            Random ran = new Random();
            switch (ran.Next(2))
            {
                case 0:
                    return one;
                default:
                    return two;
            }
        }
то есть в коде это всё будет выглядить красиво, примерно так:

stroka = "на столе стоит "+rand("теплый","холодный")+" стакан, а за окном "+rand("утро","вечер");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно крутить как угодно, первое что пришло в голову

```
string stroka ="стакан";
string[] arr = {"теплый","холодный"};
Console.WriteLine(stroka+" "+arr[new Random().Next(0, arr.Length-1)]);
```

Если нужно именно функцией, то можно так:

```
public string ArrayRand(String stroka, String[] arr)
{
    return stroka += " "+arr[new Random().Next(0, arr.Length-1)];
}
```

Comment: да, но это тоже не удобно, грамоздко... представте если это не два слова, а целый абзац...

Comment: добавил в ответ функцию, вернее скачать метод :)

Comment: Как-то это слишком банально, @johniek_comp

Comment: вообще-то метод `.Next()` исключает верхний предел, т.о. `.Next(0, arr.Length-1)` никогда не вернёт последнее слово из массива

Comment: Ага, точно. Явный тому пример:

     rand.Next(0, 1);  // всегда 0

Answer (score 4):

Вот однострочник:

```
var stroka = new Random().Next(2) == 0 ? "стакан холодный" : "стакан теплый";
```

Answer (score 3):

Вот вы пишите (в комментарии  под первым ответом):

> да, но это тоже не удобно, грамоздко... представте если это не два слова, а целый абзац, где десятки слов которые должны подставиться случайно. в общем по сути это генеротор уникальных текстов получается

В таком случае могу предложить такое вот решение, додумать до конца должны сами, ведь слова в абзаце могут разделять и точки, и запятые, и прочие знаки препинания. Вот идея:

```
 ...
            // наш абзац со словами =)
            string strings = "hot cold red blue white old new green light";
            // и вот мы их разбиваем на словечки, далее - стандартная схема!
            string[] words = strings.Split(' ');
            string mainword = "cap is ";
            Random rand = new Random();
            int num = rand.Next(0, words.Length);
            mainword += words[num];
            MessageBox.Show(mainword);
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно еще так, добавить `extension` для массива. К примеру :

```
string stroka ="стакан";
string[] arr = {"теплый","холодный"};
Console.WriteLine(arr.Rnd());
```

и Класс расширений для массива

```
public static class ArrayExtensions
    {
        public static string Random(this string[] arr)
        {
            return arr[new Random().Next(0, arr.Length - 1)];
        }
    }
```

То же самое, что предлагал johniek_comp, только удобней в использовании, имхо.

Comment: вообще-то метод `.Next()` исключает верхний предел, т.о. `.Next(0, arr.Length-1)` никогда не вернёт последнее слово из массива

Comment: вообще очень даже хорошее решение, только добавить немного обобщённости:

    public static T Rnd<T>(this T[] arr)
    {
        return arr[new Random().Next(0, arr.Length)];
    }